# Can't get ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I need to call an ejs file in another ejs file and exactly in function but i have always "can not get file"
If i do an include file outside the function.It works.
But I need to call this ejs file in the function.

```
<input type = "submit" value = "heure"  id="sub" style="width:120px" onclick="changer()"/>
<input type = "submit" value = "journée" id="sub1" style="width:120px" onclick="changersub1()"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function changersub1()
    {
         document.getElementById("sub1").style.backgroundColor="MistyRose";

         document.getElementById("sub").style.backgroundColor="white";

         window.location = "./index1.ejs";
    } 
 </script>
```

Do you have any idea please? Thanks

Comment: you can't directly access ejs file from client side.You need to create a route to render `index1.ejs` then add this to your client side `window.location = "/route-url";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the following line

```
window.location = "./index1.ejs";
```

you are trying to call something like **localhost:5000/index1.ejs** which is wrong. **Index1.ejs** is a *template file* which needs to be rendered on the server side as follows in **ExpressJS**

```
router.get('/index1', function(request, response) {
   response.render('index1.ejs');
});
```

add the above line to your routes and change the function to following

```
window.location = "/index1";
```